# How do you assign a value to a variable if no value is assigned, but, keep the value if one is assigned?

Tags: python, variables, recursion, python-2.7

I am currently defining a recursive function. It's goal is to sort from lowest to highest. When it starts out I want A to equal 0 but I want the value to increase by one every time through the loop. Is this possible? Here is the function so far.

```
def my_sort(number):
    if a is None:
        a=0
        b=1
    separated = number.split(',')
    if separated[a]<= separated[b]:
        while separated[0]<=separated[1]:
            a = a+1
            b = b+1
            my_sort(number)
        while separated[0]>separated[1]:
            my_sort(number)

    else:
        new=0
        separated[a] = new
        separated[a].replace(separated[a],separated[b])
        separated[b].replace(separated[b],new)


user_input= input("values to sort")
user_input= my_sort(user_input)
print user_input
```

Answer (score 3):

A better approach would be to pass 'a' and 'b' as arguments to my_sort().  Then your initial invocation is `my_sort(user_input, 0, 1)` and your recursive call is `my_sort(number, a+1, b+1)`.

If you don't like passing 'a' and 'b' to my_sort(), then define `my_sort_helper()` that uses 'a' and 'b' as parameters and implement my_sort as `my_short_helper (input, 0, 1)`

Comment: Better yet, make `a` and `b` arguments with default values. `def my_sort(number, a=0, b=1): ...`

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question it would be just: `a = a or 0`

Answer (score 1):

Building on @GoZoner's approach, I would suggest pre-splitting the `numbers` string into a list and passing it to your `my_sort` function instead of the original string. This way, for the recursion, you invoke it with a slice of the parameter, as in `nums[2:]`.

Also, since `b` will always equal `a + 1`, you don't need it.

A final suggestion: don't assign the sorted result to `user_input`. As soon as you changed it, it should be called something else.